# I want to centre my navigation bar, aiming to leave up to 5 pixels on either side of the bar without moving any of my tabs in the bar itself

Tags: html, css

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}


  

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}


ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

<I honestly have no idea what is wrong with my code, and I wouldn't be surprised if there was conflicting code throughout this.>

< I want to align the bar itself so that there are white spaces on the edge of it without moving the tabs in my bar. Any help is muchly appreciated.>

Comment: Add the screenshot of your web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use `ul{ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }` Or Insert Your HTML Elements to a `<center></center>` Tag.
Eg:

```
<center>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</center>
```

**But** If you are using your navigation bar full width

*Use*

```
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```